# How to add role selection field to the registration form?

Tags: users, forms

How can I add the role to registration form that users can choose their role?

I tested the [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module and the [Auto Assign Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module but they don't do what I want.

I want to add a CCK field in the admin/configure/account/fields.

**Is there any module to add a CCK field to registration form for choosing the role?**

Comment: Did you test the module? https://drupal.org/project/user_selectable_roles

Comment: I believe you can combine https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath with profile 2. These would allow you setup 2 or more registration paths. You can then tell your users to Register as student or Register as a teacher.

Comment: This module has become redundant and will NOT be ported to Drupal 7. I recommend using Auto Assign Role, which does the same thing and more.

Comment: No I don't to have different address for registration. at now my problem is adding role selection to the cck of the registration form

Answer (score 1):

If any module doesn't fit yoour requirement then you can use the  below code
 You can create any custom module or put this code in template.php of your theme.
 function testing_custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){

```
if($form_id=="user_register_form"){
    $result = db_select('role', 'r')
                ->fields('r',array('rid','name'))
                ->condition('name',array('administrator','anonymous user'),'NOT IN')
                ->execute()
                ->fetchAll();
    $role   =   array();
    foreach($result as $userRole){

        $role[$userRole->rid] = $userRole->name;
    }

$form['role']['#type'] = "select";
$form['role']['#options'] =$role;
$form['role']['#required'] = 1;
$form['role']['#size']='auto';
    $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_assign_role';

} 

}


function custom_assign_role(&$form, $form_state){
   $uid=  $form_state['values']['uid'];

    user_multiple_role_edit(array($uid), 'add_role', $form_state['values']['role']);

}

Hope it will help!
```

Answer (score 1):

Role selection actually already exists on the user registration form, it's just not accessible for unauthenticated users.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Display the roles selection.
  $form['account']['roles']['#access'] = TRUE;

  // Get available roles.
  $roles = array_map('check_plain', user_roles(TRUE));

  // Unset system roles.
  unset($roles[DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID]);
  unset($roles[DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID]);

  // Add options without system roles.
  $form['account']['roles']['#options'] = $roles;
}
```

Where the user_account_form is built: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_account_form/7

Where the user_account_form is included in the user_register_form: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_register_form/7

Answer (score 0):

You can add field called as field_role over here `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` and assign various roles to it.You can use select list.

Based on role selected while registering you can assign that role to the user by using rules module.

- Rules module you can compare text comparison for the selected field_role by user while registering.
- Based on that you can assign user the role what you want to assign for each text.

Example:

```
     Seller as Seller(Roles)

     Editor as Editor(Roles) etc
```